# Library for extracting words (speech) out from audio stream?

Tags: audio, extract, speech

I have an audio stream and I would extract words (speech) from it. So for example having audio.wav I would get 001.wav, 002.wav, 003.wav, etc where each XXX.wav is one word.

I am looking for a library or program to do it -- platform does not matter, but I prefer open-source solution.

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 2):

[Nuance](http://www.nuance.com/naturallyspeaking/), the company that makes [Dragon Naturally Speaking](http://www.nuance.com/naturallyspeaking/), has a number of [Software Development Kits](http://www.nuance.com/naturallyspeaking/products/sdk/developers.asp).

The [Audio Mining](http://www.nuance.com/naturallyspeaking/products/sdk/sdk_audiomining.asp) kit seems to match your requirements:

> Dragon NaturallySpeaking SDK
>   AudioMining is a speaker-independent
>   speech recognition toolkit that
>   enables the indexing of 100% of the
>   speech information within audio files.
>   The technology uses highly accurate
>   speech recognition to turn audio files
>   into XML text with timestamp
>   information. This can be integrated
>   with standard text-search products to
>   enable rapid access to specific audio
>   content.

The speech to speech+metadata is far and away the hardest part to get right. Once you have the speech + metadata, extracting the words as individual audio files is [much more straightforward](http://theyougen.blogspot.com/2010/06/talk-to-me-have-fun-with-your-fun-with.html).

Comment: NB The Audio Mining kit mentioned comes with the following caveat: "** Dragon AudioMining technology is designed specifically for US English and is not intended for the transcription of meetings or interviews. **"

Comment: It's very difficult to find information on Nuance AudioMining online. And it seems to be contradictory, since the transcription of meetings and interviews was explicitly mentioned at the product launch back in 1999: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yagvFY_rUwM